# Hard understanding 'echo' from associative array structure

Tags: php, html, associative-array

So, I get this assoc array structure :

```
pastebin.com/9nEGKsK0
```

How can I fetch the urls by 'foreach'?
Help.

Comment: Please add your attempt so far.

Comment: Is there a reason you gave the address at pastebin rather than pasting the data into the question and formatting it using the button that indents it by four spaces? Looking at the structure I could make assumptions that other data would be similar, but that would be making a lot of assumptions, it would be better to both include the example data, and also provide more description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 <?php foreach($array['response']['items'] as $item) {
         foreach($item['sizes'] as $size) {
             echo $size['url'];
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? The OP asked for a solution containing `foreach`, and your answer does only use `print_r`